# Булевы триггеры

Tags: ruby

В книге "Язык программирования Ruby" авторы Мацумото, Флэнаган есть код:

```
(1..10).each {|х| print х if х==3..х==5 }
```

вывод следующий **345** дальше идет бред:

> Триггер состоит из двух булевых выражений, объединенных оператором .., в контексте условия или цикла. Триггерное выражение вычисляется в **false** до тех пор, пока левое выражение вычисляется в ***true***(может быть должно быть false).
>
> Как только это выражение приобретает значение **true**, выражение «перебрасывается» в устойчивое состояние **true**. Оно будет оставаться в этом состоянии, и последующие вычисления будут возвращать **true** до тех пор, пока правое выражение вычисляется в ***true***(может надо было пока правое выражение не вычислиться в true).
>
> Когда это случится, триггер «перебрасывается» назад, в устойчивое состояние **false**. Последующие вычисления выражения возвращают **false** до тех пор, пока левое выражение снова не станет равно ***true***.

Про триггер с 3 точками перевод еще хуже.

> Разница в том, что при использовании оператора .. когда триггер перебрасывается в true, он возвращает true, но также тестирует свое правое выражение, чтобы посмотреть, не должно ли оно перебросить его внутреннее состояние обратно в false. **При использовании оператора ... прежде тестируется правое выражение.**

---

```
(1..10).each {|х| print х if х==3..х==5 }
```

1. левое выражение 1, 2 == 3 (**false**) состояние: **false**
2. левое выражение 3 == 3 (**true**) меняет состояние на: **true** возвращает **true** идет проверка правой части (**false**).
3. левое выражение 4 == 3 (**false**) состояние остается: **true** так как правое выражение 4 == 5 **false**
4. левое выражение 5 == 3 (**false**) состояние остается: **true** проверка правого выражения 5 == 5 (**true**) перебрасываем в состояние **false**.
5. 6,7,8,9,10 == 3 (**false**) состояние не меняется.

Ну а с ... точками что то я запутался.

Comment: О да, flip-flop'ы. Фича языка, за использование которой любой ваш коллега-рубист будет готов сделать с вами нечто очень нехорошее, и которую всё никак не могут выкинуть из Ruby ко всем чертям за ненадобностью... %)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition1)..(condition2)
  # do something
end
```

Идея в том, что если первое условие истинно, то переключается невидимый рычаг, и с этого момента условие будет выполняться, пока второе условие тоже не станет истинным. Пример:

```
(1..20).each do |i|
  puts i if (i == 3)..(i == 15)
end
```

Оно напечатает все числа с 3 до 15, но если 15 будет пропущено в цикле, то оно так и продолжит печатать.

Comment: А так (1..20).each do |i|
  puts i if (i == 3)...(i == 15)
end как идет проверка

Comment: для этого примера результат такойже. но триггеры преключаются по разному и в случае сложных условий результат может отличаться

Comment: триггер это не чему равно твоё условие, а произошло ли переключение состояния с одного на другое - поэтому в оригинале правильно

Comment: триггер это не чему равно твоё условие, а произошло ли переключение состояния с одного на другое. Вот как раз этого предложения и не хватает в переводе. Спасибо.

Comment: во втором абзаце ты кажется прав `(может надо было пока правое выражение не вычислиться в true).`

Answer (score 0):

Разница между .. и ... заключается в том, что в первом случае проверяются **сразу** два условия, а во втором случае — только одно условие.

```
[1, 5, 3, 7, 9, 3, 0]. each {|х| print х if х==3...х==3 }
```

Этот код напечатает 3793. Однако, если использовать .. то будет напечатано 33.

Подробнее.
При ...
Встречаем первую 3-ку и наше выражение переключается в true. Второе выражение не вычисляется. Далее проверяем только второе выражение пока не встретим вторую 3-ку.

При ..
Встречаем первую 3-ку, выражение становится true, печатаем это число и сразу вычисляем второе выражение => false.